# Weird moderator behaviour

Tags: discussion

I wrote an answer to the *[TL-WN725N not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/32948/31379)* question.
And it seemed from the begining that @goldilocks (moderator) didn't like it.
Instead of discussing, the guy just kept on mofifying my answer trying to improve it his way, ending up modifying it almost completely.

I thought Stack Exchange worked this way:

- if you feel an answer is needs improvement, discuss about it on a comment or by chat.
- if you feel an answer is wrong/misleading you still can discuss about it and downvote.
- If you want a better answer, just write yours.
- but you can still edit to add readability / fixing typos / etc...

I of course can make mistakes. But I don't want other people to talk in my name and potentially introduce mistakes in my name (not saying it is the case right now).

Then, I have lost 12 reputation points, I guess for my comment saying I rolled back... I don't really care about those points. But I'm just wondering if that guy's behaviour is normal...

What should I do? Report?
Or is it just right to drastically mofify one's answer?

Comment: As a comment for posterity, since I did not answer here and I don't want people to think I totally ignored this: A.K. and I had a long discussion in private chat subsequently which I think led to a mutual understanding, and leaving the actual Q&A in decent shape.

Comment: Agreed. I guess the line of conduct to follow in such cases is just discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I have read through the Q&A, comments and chat transcripts. There seems to be a fair amount of disagreement between the two of you with regards to this question. In the end the edits were rolled back, @Goldilocks also added his own answer to the question, offered to change his vote, and left comments regarding your answer - while this may not have been a perfect example of how SO and this site specifically should work - in the end it worked exactly as you described.

Please remember that moderators are human too. We can be wrong and we do make mistakes.

Comment: Yes moderator are humans, and they of course have to moderate and thus need some authority. But in this case, @goldilocks is just going a bit too far. He is being insulting in comments talking about my ego. and in chat prettending I'm Evil... I really don't understand...

Comment: such behaviour doesn't make people (or at least me) want to help.

Answer (score -1):

obviously, as put, it doesn't feel like a normal behavior.

That said, I think there are some ways to report abnormal behaviors that will probably help you better than posting it as a question but I can understand that you probably want to debate/talk about it. [edit: actually I can't find a page about mediation, if someone can point it out that'd be great]

I've been moderating on some websites for 11 years now and I can tell you one thing: it's not as easy as it seems.
I think most moderators have a strong will to do things right but sometimes you face people that really piss you off on purpose and as human beings you can't always keep the cool. (not saying that's what happened here)

Although I guess we all aknowledge this, we must also aknowledge that there are bounds not to be crossed and that if abnormal behaviors tend to occur again and again, then maybe it's time for the moderator to let it go (or for his staff to be more severe about it).

I'll add that the internet layer between people sometimes fails providing peacefull communication

Answer (score -2):

Didn't do much for me either. I found the response to my suggestion insulting, but consistent with other behaviors I'm seeing here.